# Why is NSLayoutConstraint's identifier property not working in code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to write some conditions where the same constraint is not added twice. For example if a view already has a bottom anchor constraint do not add it again. So I tried using the layout constraint identifier to uniquely identify a constraint so that if it is already exists dont add another constraint again. I do not have a storyboard, so I have written the below code:

```
class PDFViewer: UIViewController {
     var quickLookController = QLPreviewController()
    
     override func viewDidLoad()

     if let quickView = quickLookController.view {
            self.view.addSubview(quickView)
     }

     {
        quickLookController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        quickLookController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        quickLookController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        quickLookController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        setPDFViewHeight(height: 100)
        setPDFViewHeight(height: 100)

    }
    
    open func setPDFViewHeight(height: CGFloat) {
        
        var isBottomAnchorSet = false
        
        if let superView = quickLookController.view.superview {
            for constraints in superView.constraints {
                if constraints.identifier == "bottom" {
                    isBottomAnchorSet = true
                }
                else {
                    print(false)
                }
            }
        }
        
        if !isBottomAnchorSet {
            quickLookController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).identifier = "bottom"
            quickLookController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

But both times I am calling `setPDFViewHeight` method it says there is not identifier named `"bottom"` but it should the second time. I have also tried to get the constraints of the super view directly like below but the same issue there as well.

```
        for constraints in view.constraints {
            if constraints.identifier == "bottom" {
                isBottomAnchorSet = true
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong or does this identifier cannot be used this way?

Even an entirely different answer on how to avoid duplication of Layout constraints would also help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your situation it's better to keep the bottom constraint and just update the constant later on, when needed, like this:

```
class PDFViewer: UIViewController {
     var quickLookController = QLPreviewController()
     var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    
     override func viewDidLoad()

     if let quickView = quickLookController.view {
            self.view.addSubview(quickView)
     }

     quickLookController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     bottomConstraint = quickLookController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        quickLookController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        quickLookController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        quickLookController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navView.bottomAnchor),
        bottomConstraint
     ])
        
     setPDFViewHeight(height: 100)
     setPDFViewHeight(height: 100)

    
    open func setPDFViewHeight(height: CGFloat) {
        bottomConstraint.constant = height
    }
}
```

Also the naming of the `setPDFViewHeight` may be misleading, because what it really does is that it set's the offset from the anchor, not the absolute height.

Comment: Should I call ```layoutSubviews()``` as well every time ```setPDFViewHeight()``` is called?. I have noted your point in the function name. Will come up with a more correct one. Thanks

Comment: @RohithS Don't call `layoutSubviews()` directly, call `layoutIfNeeded()` instead. You can read more about the difference in this nice article https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-swift-setneedslayout-vs-layoutifneeded-vs-layoutsubviews-5a2b486da31c

Comment: Thanks. This did it!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are creating TWO bottom constraints:

```
// this creates a constraint
//  with an identifier
//  but does not activate it
quickLookController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).identifier = "bottom"

// this creates a constraint
//  WITHOUT an identifier
//  and activates it
quickLookController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Give this a try:

```
open func setPDFViewHeight(height: CGFloat) {
    
    var isBottomAnchorSet = false

    if let superView = quickLookController.view.superview {
        for constraint in superView.constraints {
            print("constraint identifier:", constraint.identifier ?? "no id", constraint)
            if constraint.identifier == "bottom" {
                isBottomAnchorSet = true
                print("Bottom Anchor already set")
            }
        }
        if !isBottomAnchorSet {
            print("Creating Bottom Anchor")
            let c = quickLookController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            c.identifier = "bottom"
            c.isActive = true
        }
    }

}
```

To test it, replace your double call with:

```
print("First call")
print()
setPDFViewHeight(height: 100)

print()
print("Second call")
print()
setPDFViewHeight(height: 100)
```

Here's the output I get:

```
First call

constraint identifier: no id <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002086030 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fbfa5407fa0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fbfa54084d0 )>
constraint identifier: no id <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002085fe0 UIView:0x7fbfa5407fa0.trailing == UIView:0x7fbfa54084d0.trailing   (active)>
constraint identifier: no id <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002085f40 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fbfa5407fa0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fbfa54084d0 )>
Creating Bottom Anchor

Second call

constraint identifier: no id <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002086030 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fbfa5407fa0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fbfa54084d0 )>
constraint identifier: no id <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002085fe0 UIView:0x7fbfa5407fa0.trailing == UIView:0x7fbfa54084d0.trailing   (active)>
constraint identifier: no id <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002085f40 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fbfa5407fa0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fbfa54084d0 )>
constraint identifier: bottom <NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000208bc00 'bottom' UIView:0x7fbfa5407fa0.bottom == UIView:0x7fbfa54084d0.bottom   (active)>
Bottom Anchor already set
```